# .NET Core 2.0 Console app - Logging add new LogLevel

Tags: logging, asp.net-core, .net-core

I'm rewriting a server side console application (written with .NET Framework), that will need to log messages to various places. The current logging system is custom written by my colleagues. But I think, that with the current Logging framework, provided in .NET Core (Microsoft.Extensions.Logging), with some custom providers, we can achieve the desired logging in different places. The issue I have is that this framework offers five different Log Levels (Trace,Debug, Information, Warning, Error, Critical).
In the other logger, we have all this level of logging, but we have some other levels, that we need to be there.
So my question is there any way that I can use this current .NET framework and just add the needed log levels?
My google search ended miserably...

Thanks for the help in advance!
Julian Dimitrov

Comment: No, the log levels are *fixed* as they are [defined as an enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.logging.loglevel) that you cannot change. I doubt you actually need more log *levels* though. Most applications actually don’t even make use of most of the log levels… So I would assume that you are using log levels incorrectly. Can you give some more information about what kind of levels you have and why you need them?

Comment: Well, I'm looking in the source code of the existing application, and there are defined LogLevels as follows: `None`, `Emergency`,`Alert`,`Critical`,`Error`,`Warning`,`Notice`,`Informational`,`Debug`
This application is connected to one central logging system, and I think if we do not send the proper log levels, it should cause a problem in the central logging system. I have to check!

Comment: IMO: `Emergency == Critical`, `Alert == Warning`, `Notice == Informational == Information`. Brings you down to 5 levels. But you should probably look at the usages of those log levels to tell if they are being used correctly like that.